# org.tukaani.xz.CorruptedInputException: Compressed data is corrupt while extracting 7z archive File in java

Tags: java, compression, 7zip, apache-commons-compress

Getting org.tukaani.xz.CorruptedInputException: Compressed data is corrupt error while extracting 7z file. i am using common-compress-1.21.jar and xz-1.9.jar.here is my code

```
    File f = new File("/home/local/Documents/7zFile/7zFile.7z");
    InputStream inputStream;
    ArchiveEntry entry = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!inputStream.markSupported()) {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    }
       
    inputStream.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    byte[] inputData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    inputStream.reset();
    SeekableInMemoryByteChannel channel = new              
                                   SeekableInMemoryByteChannel(inputData);        
    sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(channel);
            while ((sevenZFile!=null && (entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null)) {
                             System.out.print(entry.getName());                                  
            }
```

stackTrace of error

```
org.tukaani.xz.CorruptedInputException: Compressed data is corrupt
at org.tukaani.xz.LZMAInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.ChecksumVerifyingInputStream.read(ChecksumVerifyingInputStream.java:88)
at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.copyRange(IOUtils.java:330)
at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.copyRange(IOUtils.java:301)
at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readRange(IOUtils.java:350)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readEncodedHeader(SevenZFile.java:706)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.initializeArchive(SevenZFile.java:544)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readHeaders(SevenZFile.java:474)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:343)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:255)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:183)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:167)
```

in this line `sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(channel);` its throwing error.

i have created 7z archive file in ubuntu OS for this file its throwing exception, the 7z archive which i created online website its working fine. is there any issue with ubuntu? and how to fix this?
[image: e]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please read the [tag:apache] tag description before adding it _again_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LZMA data has an end of stream marker. Such .7z files are valid but quite uncommon. XZ for Java 1.9 added a feature specifically. please find this link for better understanding. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COMPRESS-591

https://sourceforge.net/p/lzmautils/discussion/708858/thread/822d80d5ea/