# I'm getting a problem with apache commons compress

Tags: android, 7zip, apache-commons-compress

I'm getting this error while extracting a .7z protected file

org.tukaani.xz.CorruptedInputException: Compressed data is corrupt

and I'm using this code

```
public static void unSevenZipFile(String from,String to,String pass) throws Exception
{
    // Get 7zip file.
    SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(from),pass.getBytes("UTF16LE"));

    SevenZArchiveEntry entry;
    while ((entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {

        File file = new File(to + entry.getName());
        Log.d("unzip","Un seven zipping - " + file);
        // Create directory before streaming files.
        String dir = file.toPath().toString().substring(0, file.toPath().toString().lastIndexOf("/"));
        Files.createDirectories(new File(dir).toPath());
        // Stream file content
        byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
        sevenZFile.read(content);
        Files.write(file.toPath(), content);
        
    }


}
```

if You know what's the problem please tell me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: And i've tried this also  File(from),pass.getBytes("UTF-16LE"))

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447).

Comment: This is my first time at doing a post

Comment: ...and you did well. No hard feelings, you did well by editing your question. Thank you.  (unfortunately I can't help you with the problem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.tukaani.xz.CorruptedInputException: Compressed data is corrupt while extracting 7z archive File in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080433/org-tukaani-xz-corruptedinputexception-compressed-data-is-corrupt-while-extract)

Comment: I found the problem it was the dash I have placed it in the wrong place ,it needs to like this "UTF16-LE" ,I fell embarrassed

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I didn't place the dash in the right place.
I did both this "UTF16LE" and "UTF-16LE"
but the solution was this "UTF16-LE"

Comment: Are you able to extract a 7z file of around 15MB size using apache?